# Converting array objects to lower case for comparison in CosmosDB Query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to make our queries case insensitive. This means queries in Cosmos DB using array_contains and trying to convert the value to lower case.

I've tried various iterations of LOWER() wrapping the values in the query, but nothing seems to work for converting the value from the array to lower case. It's also important it's an exact match not fuzzy. This is of course also within a query in Power BI in our model so it's querying Cosmos DB with M code.

let

```
querystring = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.properties.Type ='Noon' and array_contains(c.properties.Clients, '" & DynamicClientList & "' )", 

results = DocumentDB.Contents(DocumentDBURL, Env & ".ImoData","Collected", [Query=querystring])
```

in

```
results
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to store your searchable metadata content as lower-case (even if this means storing a 2nd array, for searching purposes). There is no case-insensitive search ability, and when resorting to something like `LOWER()`, at that point, you won't be taking advantage of indexes.